# Trying to parse JSON with underscore (Unexpected token on Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, underscore.js

Hello I am trying to get a grasp on underscore.js

i have a json file as follows:

```
[
{
    "name":"rocky",
    "last-updated": "Yesterday", 
    "age":"32"
},
{
    "name":"annie",
    "last-updated": "Today",
     "age":"31"
}
]
```

And a javascript function:

```
    function getNames() {
        var users = $.ajax({
            url : "users.json",
            async : false
        });

        var names = _.map(JSON.parse(users.responseText),
            function(user) {
                return user.name
            });

        return names;

    }
```

It works fine on IE but on Chrome, it throws me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

on this line:

```
var names = _.map(JSON.parse(users.responseText),function(user) {return user.name});
```

As far as I know this error is because of trying to parse object not the JSON string. Am i right? How do I solve this? It works on IE?

Thank you!

Comment: i thought json's opening and closing brackets where `{}`, and `[]` where for array

Comment: Thats not underscore thats a hyphen!

Comment: Avoid - chars in you key's

Comment: @gwillie:I replaced [] with {} on json file, still same error

Comment: @meda: you mean _.map ? i am sure its underscore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out the problem was with **url** parameter.

```
 url : "users.json"
 url: "/users.json"
```

Error thrown by Chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

After an hour of troubleshooting, i found out:
**Chrome has a bug on caching GET requests.**

It can be fixed by setting

```
cache: false
```

on my Ajax call!

Also making a directory and calling that directory on **url** seems to be working.

```
url : "json/users.json"
```

Thanks to those who tried to help.